# Manipulating data in CSV

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pandas

Using Python 3 and numpy, I am trying to read and manipulate a CSV. My intent is to find all buildings that are over 50,000 square feet, the data for which is in column 6. The interpreter returns an error stating, "Line # (got 1 columns instead of 11)." I think that my issue is registering the data type as a string, but I have tried different data types and cannot get the script to work.

```
import numpy as np
dataframe = np.genfromtxt('buildingsv1.csv', dtype=str, skip_header=1, delimiter="none",usecols=(6))
headers = next(dataframe)
for row in dataframe: 
    if 50000 in row(6):
       print(row)
np.savetxt('buildingsv2')
```

**SOLUTION** (using Pandas instead of Numpy)

```
import pandas as pd
total_df = pd.read_csv('buildingsv1.csv', keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""])
#Build new DataFrame of 4 columns
total_df[['PARCELID', 'KIVAPIN', 'ADDRESS', 'APN']]   
total_df[total_df.sqft >= 50000]
```

A version of the [raw dataset](https://data.kcmo.org/Property/Large-Buildings-in-Kansas-City-Missouri-2015-/ir87-xdcg) is available. I am using a desktop version with machine-readable headings and more columns.

Comment: Impossible to help without knowing what your data looks like.

Comment: You should define a delimiter. Can you show a sample of your buildingsv1.csv file?

Comment: Have you considered using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org)? It's much easier than using raw `numpy`.

Comment: @MattDMo I had begun the project using Pandas, but thought that Pandas was better for analysis and Numpy was better for data manipulation. I will revisit Pandas if that's what you suggest.

Comment: Are you trying read this as one string per line?  But then you won't have column 6. How about a plain Python file read, one line at a time?

Comment: @jcm Pandas is built on top of numpy, so you're already using it, just in an easier format.

Comment: I posted a image of the raw data @jyvet

Comment: @hpaulj - I removed the data type and added the delimiter and got an error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not an iterator.

Comment: @hpaulj - ultimately I need to create a new csv output with select columns and rows, so I don't think your Python suggestion would work.

Comment: It would be better if you gave us a sample of the `csv` file, not an image of the spread sheet.  That said, I'm guessing it is comma delimited with mixed datatypes (int, float, string), and possibly headers. If so this is a straight forward use of `genfromtxt`, that has been discussed many times.

Comment: `genfromtxt` has several examples of comma delimited inputs with mixed types.  The doc uses StringIO, but you can make matching files with an editor.  Play with those examples.  Look at the results in an interactive Python shell.

Comment: From what I can tell, your delimiter is the problem.  If your file is literally a csv, where data is separated by commas, when delimiter='none' and you run your sample code above, it returns  "Line # (got 1 columns instead of 11).".  If you try to print `dataframe` after running the script, it doesn't exist because `genfromtxt` failed.  When you put `delimiter=','`, then print `dataframe`, you see that it does print but you have a new error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not an iterator`. I think it's because you're trying to do `next()` on a numpy array outside of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general idea using Pandas (which is built on Numpy).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# I generated df below but you'd want to read the data with pd.read_csv() like so
#df = pd.read_csv('buildingsv1.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 6)*100000,
                  columns=['Column'+str(i) for i in range(1, 7)])

new_df = df[df['Column6'] >= 50000]
```

It's good practice to check `dtypes` in Pandas using `df.dtypes`.  Your data will need to be numeric first to filter over 50,000.

If your numeric data has commas (ex: `50,000`), it can be problematic.  Here's an example with a column that contains commas.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Other Data': [2, 3, 44, 5, 65, 6], 'Commas1': [' 68,028,616 ', ' 162,470,071 ', ' 135,393,045 ', ' 89,981,894 ', ' 74,787,888 ', ' 173,610,498 ']})
>>> df1
         Commas1  Other Data
0    68,028,616            2
1   162,470,071            3
2   135,393,045           44
3    89,981,894            5
4    74,787,888           65
5   173,610,498            6

>>> df1.dtypes
Commas1       object
Other Data     int64
dtype: object
```

One way to convert `Commas1` column is to use regex:

```
df1['Commas1'] = df1['Commas1'].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]', '').astype('int64')

>>> df1
     Commas1  Other Data
0   68028616           2
1  162470071           3
2  135393045          44
3   89981894           5
4   74787888          65
5  173610498           6
>>> df1.dtypes
Commas1       int64
Other Data    int64
dtype: object
```

The takeaway is, `Commas1` has been converted to an integer datatype in this example.  You can change `int64` to `float64` for example if you need floats instead of ints.

Comment: But the OP is having problems reading the file in the first place.  You are generating a random dataframe and then doing his testing.  That's ok, but it doesn't help with the file read.

Comment: You're right. I would use `df = pd.read_csv('buildingsvs.csv')` from which point the above becomes more relevant.  I'm not as familiar with `np.genfromtxt` but was taking a stab at it since the OP mentioned he had begun the project using Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample run with a comma delimited csv (with numpy)

Simulate a file with a list of lines.

```
In [168]: txt="""name, val1, val2, val3
me, 23, 34, 34
you, 34, 22, 35
he, 22, 66, 66
she, 36,32,36
"""
In [169]: txt=txt.splitlines()
```

Load with `genfromtxt`:

```
In [170]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None, delimiter=',')
In [171]: data
Out[171]: 
array([['name', ' val1', ' val2', ' val3'],
       ['me', ' 23', ' 34', ' 34'],
       ['you', ' 34', ' 22', ' 35'],
       ['he', ' 22', ' 66', ' 66'],
       ['she', ' 36', '32', '36']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

oops, it loaded strings - because the first line is names.

Skip the first line:

```
In [174]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None, skip_header=1,delimiter=',')
In [175]: data
Out[175]: 
array([('me', 23, 34, 34), ('you', 34, 22, 35), ('he', 22, 66, 66),
       ('she', 36, 32, 36)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S3'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

It deduced the column types correctly, but gave them generic names.  `names=True` to use column headers from the file:

```
In [176]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None, names=True,delimiter=',')
In [177]: data
Out[177]: 
array([('me', 23, 34, 34), ('you', 34, 22, 35), ('he', 22, 66, 66),
       ('she', 36, 32, 36)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S3'), ('val1', '<i4'), ('val2', '<i4'), ('val3', '<i4')])
```

`data` is a 1d array, with 4 records; the fields of those records are defined in the `dtype`.

Now we can display rows from this array according to some column criteria:

```
In [179]: for row in data:
    if row['val2']>32:
        print(row)
   .....:         
('me', 23, 34, 34)
('he', 22, 66, 66)
```

One record:

```
In [181]: data[0]
Out[181]: ('me', 23, 34, 34)
```

One field (column):

```
In [182]: data['name']
Out[182]: 
array(['me', 'you', 'he', 'she'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Those selected values can be collected into a new array with an expression like:

```
In [205]: data1=data[data['val2']>32]
In [206]: data1
Out[206]: 
array([('me', 23, 34, 34), ('he', 22, 66, 66)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S3'), ('val1', '<i4'), ('val2', '<i4'), ('val3', '<i4')])
```

Writing a matching `csv` isn't quite so nice with `numpy`.  It has a `savetxt` that writes data in columns, but you have to specify format and header.

```
In [207]: header='name, val1, val2, val3'
In [208]: fmt='%10s, %4d, %4d, %4d'
In [209]: np.savetxt('test.csv',data1, fmt=fmt,header=header)
In [210]: cat test.csv
# name, val1, val2, val3
     'me',   23,   34,   34
     'he',   22,   66,   66
```

Comment: You have done a great job of walking me through genfromtxt. I realize now that a key mistake I made was incorrect syntax in the conditional indexing statement [if row...]. Now I am getting an "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices."